# Phalcon\Tag::linkTo URL not containing the subfolder where the project lives

Tags: php, url-rewriting, phalcon

I am following the [tutorial](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/reference/tutorial-invo.html) on OS X 10.8 with PHP 5.3, phalcon 0.5.0. I have a folder called `tutorial` in the web root of my apache. When I use the code:

```
echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo("signup", "Sign Up Here!");
```

In the output html I am getting

```
localhost/signup
```

instead of

```
localhost/tutorial/signup
```

I also entered RewriteBase /tutorial/ in my .htacess file, but still having the same problem. I had the same issue in 0.4 of phalcon and also in 0.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL rewrite will need to be registered in the DI container of your project during bootstrap as such (file public/index.php)

```
// Setting up the view component
$di->set(
    'url', 
    function() {
        $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/tutorial/');
        return $url;
    }
);
```

This will effectively instruct Phalcon to use the subfolder internally as well as the [\Phalcon\Tag::linkTo()](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/api/Phalcon_Tag.html) function. Please note the ending slash "/" character in the setBaseUri()

Comment: Many thanks. I've submitted a request for this code to be included in the Tutorial 1 documentation: https://github.com/phalcon/docs/issues/243